# If I'm defining a custom external font in css, do I need to declare the src for every class that uses it?

Tags: css, font-face, embedded-fonts

If I am using an externally loaded font (e.g. "MyFont") and it's going to be used in multiple classes, do I need to do this:

```
.one { font-family: MyFont; src: url( "fonts/MyFont.ttf" ); }
.two { font-family: MyFont; src: url( "fonts/MyFont.ttf" ); }
```

or can I do this?

```
.one { font-family: MyFont; src: url( "fonts/MyFont.ttf" ); }
.two { font-family: MyFont; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, check out this article: [The New Bulletproof @Font-Face Syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax)

Add something like this at the beginning of your CSS file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

Running with this sample code, the rest of your CSS should look something like:

```
.one { font-family: MyFontFamily }
.two { font-family: MyFontFamily }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`@font-face`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) directive.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url(...);
}

.one { font-family: MyFont; }
.two { font-family: MyFont; }
```